# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in where clause

Tags: oracle, jsp

```
String sql="select * from " + tname + "where '"+abc+"'='"+anyid+"' ";
```

When I execute this query then it is showing error that SQL Command not Properly ended

where tname is the variable name for table means we take table name from the user and abc is the variable that takes the name of first column of the entered table from the user and anyid is the variable that takes the data of first column of any one particular selected row of the entered table.

I am developing database GUI and I take one textbox with submit button and whenever I enter any table name in textbox then it will show the details of that table and I take edit hyperlink in every row of table details and then suppose i want to edit any row then i click on that particular edit hyperlink of row, then in next page it retrieve all the data of particular selected row from database. I give table name as 'tname' variable in textbox and i take value of 'anyid' variable by clicking on edit hyperlink and 'abc' varibel takethe first column of particuler table

Comment: Do you need a space before the where part? .... tname + " where '"

Comment: As well as the missing space and extra quotes mentioned in answers, you should consider running this as a prepared statement with a [bind variable](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/web-scripting-for-oracle.php#jsp) for `anyId` to reduce the number of hard parses. You need to think about SQL injection too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String sql="select * from " + tname + " where "+abc+"='"+anyid+"' ";
```

- add space between `tname` and *where*
- `abc` is a column name, so single quote (`'` `'`) not suppose to be there

Answer (score 1):

there should be a space before where

```
String sql="select * from " + tname + " where '"+abc+"'='"+anyid+"' ";
```